# Difference between 'get to know' and 'got to know'

Tags: word-usage

> I just checked with your team and **get to know** that you are on other call.

Is using **get to know** right here?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! No, **got to know** is better, because it's in the past tense, while **get to know** is in the present tense.

Answer (score 8):

As Subjunctive and CopperKettle say, *got* is needed here, to maintain consistency in tense. In most circumstances the final clause should be in past-tense form, too.

However, you should not use *get to know* in this context. *Get to know* is an idiom meaning "come (gradually) to a deeper knowledge or understanding of". It's most commonly used of people (*When I was in Berlin I got to know Hans Dolling pretty well*), but it can also be used of complex entities like a literary work or a field of study. It is not used of individual facts; for that you want something like *discover* or *find out*.

> I just checked with your team and found out that you were on another call.

ADDED:
Moreover, you should not use *got to find out* or *got to discover* or anything of that sort. *GET to VERB* is another idiom meaning "be allowed to *VERB* or have the opportunity to *VERB*": *Last week I got to see Citizen Kane for the first time*.

Comment: Then, how about to say "I just checked with your team and got to find out that you were on another call." as you say "know" is not proper to use there?

Comment: @EvaristeGalois See my addition.

Answer (score 1):

Since *you checked*, keep the sequences of short actions in the past, *got to know* is the choice.

Now *got to = you were given the opportunity to do something* (in this case), so besides you checked, something else came for you to do it.

Comment: I think *get/got to know* here is intended to mean *come/came to know*.

Comment: @StoneyB Now you say so, makes sense.