# Can we use "get to know" in the past?

Tags: phrase-usage

The phrase "get to know someone" is pretty much used in the present but can I use it in the past? In that case is it written as:

- I got to know him at the time but things have changed over the years.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't think it would be able to be used like that?

Comment: @Bee Never stumble upon it being used in such a way.

Comment: I've seen it used, I think think it's pretty hard to answer a question like this unless the phase can be sited from a well known source. I have certainly used it in this way before though

Comment: Here is a good example: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133220/happen-to-know-vs-came-to-know-vs-got-to-know-vs-came-across

Comment: "Got to know" is very common. For example, "I got to know him when I was in school."

Answer (score 1):

*"**Get to know** is an idiom meaning "come (gradually) to a deeper knowledge or understanding of". It's most commonly used of people ..., but it can also be used of complex entities like a literary work or a field of study."* - [StoneyB, ELL, Difference between 'get to know' and 'got to know'.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76747/difference-between-get-to-know-and-got-to-know)

The past form isn't that rare.

Here are some examples:

> 1. I got to know that album like the back of my hand. - [The New York Times](https://artsbeat.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/05/25/katie-finneran-will-be-miss-hannigan-in-annie-revival/)
> 2. That was how I got to know that I was clever. - [The New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2011/06/06/clever-girl)
> 3. Today I got to know that they were prevented from coming in. - [BBC News](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-17942197)
> 4. I really got to know her as I was doing her hair. - [Chicago Tribune](https://www.chicagotribune.com/entertainment/tv/ct-ent-bojack-chicago-alison-tafel-1031-20191030-y63twukd5ndpnbgqk52mewz2rm-story.html)
> 5. I was exposed to the kind of clients I wanted to be exposed to and got to know how people worked here. - [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/courtstroud/2019/10/29/how-one-latina-overcame-shyness-and-became-a-powerful-us-hispanic-advertising-ceo/#2431e96e2314)
> 6. Having got to know the bakers over the past nine weeks, there is something really touching about seeing snippets of their home lives. - [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2019/oct/29/the-great-british-bake-off-final-review-even-paul-hollywood-couldnt-bear-it)

Comment: Future too. I expect I will get to know Jim while we are working together next month.